# IE links and other functioning not working but works in all other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer

i am building a site that works properly in other browsers, but when i have checked it in IE(11) none of the links, :hover functions or inputs seem to work.  Javascript works in the banner but when the mouse hovers the controls don't show. layout and styling generally seem to be working fine minus a few tweaks. The most confusing thing is that i am building another site using similar framework and it works absolutely fine. I have tried different doctype and html combinations with no success and am now just using html5. I have also tried it on a other people's IE browsers and come up with the same issue, so it seems to be a global issue and not just from my IE browser. [The site can be viewed here](http://www.karma.vivid-design.co)  All the site map links are supposed to work as do all the images under the js banner. Also the menu button at the top should open up. Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't give enough informations  about your problem, more details will be good.

Comment: Hi xYuri. sorry mate, i have added a link above so you can see for yourself.

Comment: IE always late, anyway i dont think there is much people still using ie, all other browsers have more features and run everything, when i build a site i really dont care for ie, and i notify user that ie is not supported and may have problems viewing our site, and to use ff or chrome or opera.

Comment: I even think that microsoft itself doesn't use IE, lol.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. after checking every piece of code i finally found the problem. it was a z-index issue where a div was out by 1 layer and therefor covering the links. lol every other browser was fine with it. Microsoft seem to wreck everything they get their hands on just to be unique.

Comment: Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Answer (score 1):

It seems IE disable JS.Enable it.I was infected by a virus that stops js run on browsers.I checked on other PC that works fine.Chrome is well supportive for development.I reinstall windows then that project work fine.